# R - Select Elements from list that meet the criteria

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply

I had a tough time selecting elements from a list that meet a function. So documenting the same with a solution.

```
check.digits <- function(x){ grepl('^(\\d+)$' , x) }

x = "741 abc pqr street 71 15 41 510741"
lx = strsplit(x, split = " ", fixed = TRUE)
lapply(lx, check.digits)
```

This does not work -

```
lx[[1]][c(lapply(lx, check.digits))]
```

Use -

```
lx[[1]][sapply(lx, check.digits)]
```

thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given what you're after, perhaps you should just use `gregexpr` + `regmatches`:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+", x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "741"    "71"     "15"     "41"     "510741"
```

Or, from "qdapRegex", use `rm_number`:

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_number(x, extract = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "741"    "71"     "15"     "41"     "510741"
```

Or, from "stringi", use `stri_extract_all_regex`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(x, "\\d+")
# [[1]]
# [1] "741"    "71"     "15"     "41"     "510741"
```

Add an `[[1]]` at the end if you're just dealing with a single string and are just interested in the single vector.

Comment: This is faster. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
lx[[1]][sapply(lx, check.digits)]
[1] "741"    "71"     "15"     "41"     "510741"
```

Comment: There's no need for that `sapply` - `lx[[1]][check.digits(lx[[1]])]`

Comment: Want to post this answer? I was using c(check.digits(lx[[1]]) rather than simply the function as is

Comment: Just edit it in to your answer if you like, I don't need the reputation points :-)