# Replace list elements by name with another list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have the following list of strings:

```
l.1 = list(a = "aaa", b = "111", c = "a1a", d = "222")
```

I want to convert strings with digits only to numeric entries. To do that I'm using the function imported from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930333/r-select-elements-from-list-that-meet-the-criteria):

```
check.digits <- function(x){ grepl('^(\\d+)$' , x) }
```

When applied to `l.1` it returns strings with digits only:

```
l.2 = lapply(l.1[check.digits(l.1)], as.numeric)

> l.2
$b
[1] 111

$d
[1] 222
```

How to replace elements in `l.1` by those in `l.2`?

The desired outcome would be:

```
> l.1
$a
[1] "aaa"

$b
[1] 111

$c
[1] "a1a"

$d
[1] 222
```

Comment: `l.1[names(l.2)] <- l.2`

Comment: You may also consider logical indexing, i.e. `all_digit <- check.digits(l.1); l.1[all_digit] <-  lapply(l.1[all_digit], as.numeric)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use

```
l.1[names(l.2)] <- l.2
```